# Some hints/introductions/textbooks for LBM (Lattice Boltzmann methods) fluid simulation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, simulations, computational-physics

I come from a computer science background and I want to learn details about LBM in fluid simulation.

I have been searching around for a concise tutorial that tells me how LBM is used to solve a certain fluid problem(a PDE?).

Unfortunately I was depressed with the large number of advanced studies and papers that assumed prior knowledge.

I understand there exist quite a few papers on LBM fluid simulation written by computer scientists. However I am not satisfied with those work concentrating on implementation techniques on a specific device(like GPU) only.

I teach myself some basic knowledge on real analysis/ODE/PDE. And I think maybe I need some extra learning on Statistical Mechanics/Lebesgue Measure theory...
I am totally unfamiliar with these fields. I need your hints on how to choose the right direction towards understanding Lattice Boltzmann Methods.

Comment: Hi craftsman.don, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Right now your question is a bit vague, but perhaps it would be better if you simply ask how LBM is used to solve the particular fluids problem you have in mind. People will still be able to provide references if that is best.

Comment: First hit on Google gave me: http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.awi.de%2Ffileadmin%2Fuser_upload%2FResearch%2FResearch_Divisions%2FClimate_Sciences%2FPaleoclimate_Dynamics%2FModelling%2FLessons%2FEinf_Ozeanographie%2Flecture_19_Jan_2010.pdf&ei=PJJ6T-quJMWeOriPkdwC&usg=AFQjCNFLCtLugJ4CPxgZICn19-HcR3YmAQ

Comment: Palabos website http://www.palabos.org/software/lattice-boltzmann-method links to a brief video overview http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I82uCa7SHSQ

Comment: The book LBM Fundamentals and Engineering Applications with Computer Codes puts your feet on the ground.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Books

- [The Lattice Boltzmann Equation for Fluid Dynamics and Beyond](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198503989)
- [Lattice Boltzmann Method - Fundamentals and Engineering Applications with Computer Codes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0857294547)
- [Lattice Boltzmann Modeling - An Introduction for Geoscientists and Engineers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540279814)

The best book, in my opinion, is

- [Lattice Gas Cellular Automata and Lattice Boltzmann models](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540669736)

which has a chapter on the required statistical mechanics background as well.

### Reviews

- [Lattice Boltzmann simulations of soft matter systems](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-87706-6_2)
- [Lattice Boltzmann methods for fluid flows](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.fluid.30.1.329)
- [Lattice-Boltzmann Simulations of Particle-Fluid Suspensions](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1010414013942)

### Codes

- [Wikipedia - Lattice Boltzmann methods: Open source / free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Lattice_Boltzmann_methods&oldid=475576124#Open_Source_/_free_software)
- http://bernsdorf.org/research/ICMMES/
- [Lattice Boltzmann Matlab Scripts | Exolete](https://www.exolete.com/lbm/)

My suggestion is to look at some of the free codes and get it running first --reproduce the Poseuille flow. Just look at a one-component, single-relaxation time, two-dimensional model (D2Q9) first. Then you can worry about other complications.