# Introduction material for lattice field simulation

Tags: resource-recommendations, simulations, computational-physics, software, lattice-model

I am looking for introductory material of [lattice field theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_field_theory) simulation. It is better start from simple example (e.g. \phi^4) and include some source code. Is there any on-line or book which is suitable?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23196/2451